# If $x$ is a prime ideal, then $\overline{\{x\}}=V(p_x)$, where $V(x)$ is the set of prime ideals that contains $x$.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Atiyah-Macdonald has the following question:

> If $x$ is a prime ideal, then $\overline{\{x\}}=V(p_x)$, where $V(x)$ is the set of prime ideals that contains $x$.

Why can we not have a smaller closed set containing $x$? Why can $x$ itself not be a closed set, even if it is not maximal?

Comment: what's $\{p_x\}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the closed sets in the Zariski topology have the $V(I)$, where $I$ is some ideal of the ring $R$. If $\mathfrak p_x\in V(I)$, it means that $I\subset \mathfrak p_x$, whence
$$V(\mathfrak p_x)\subset V(I).$$

$x$ is closed if and only if $\,\overline{\!\{x\}\!}\,=\{x\}$, i.e. $V{\mathfrak p_x}=\{\mathfrak p_x\}$, or  the only prime ideal  containing $\mathfrak p_x$ is  $\mathfrak p_x$ itself. Doesn't this mean $\mathfrak p_x$ is maximal?

Comment: Yes but the intersections of sets of the form $V(I)$ are also closed sets. So my question is why can such an intersection not just contain $p_x$? $V(p_x)$ may not be the only closed set containing $p_x$. It may be one of many, the intersection of all of which may be just $p_x$

Comment: I showed that  $V(\mathfrak p_x)$ is a subset of any $V(I)$ having $\mathfrak p_x$ as one of its elements, hence it is the smallest closed subset!